# Install pygraphviz for python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, pygraphviz

When I try to install pygraphviz using pip, I get an error message

```
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2987): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Now, I did install both graphviz as well as Microsoft Visual Studio, so I have no idea why installation would not work. I also tried installing via GitHub clone with similiar (lack of) results. I'm new to Python and programming in general, so I'm not sure what might be the problem here.